# Learnpythonthehardway exercise 17 not working

Tags: python

I'm working on exercise 17 and can't seem to get it to run.

I run it like `python test.py raw.txt copied.txt` but receive this error:

```
Copying from raw.txt to copied.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    in_file = open(from_file)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'raw.txt'
```

My code:
    from sys import argv
    from os.path import exists

```
script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

# we could do these two on one line too, how?
in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
raw_input()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

Comment: Please, a traceback is text, you can copy and paste that here.

Comment: is `raw.txt` in your `python` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Now all files are being searched in your working dir

```
from sys import argv
from os import getcwd
from os.path import exists, join

cwd = getcwd()
script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

# we could do these two on one line too, how?
in_file = open(join(cwd, from_file))
indata = in_file.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(join(cwd, to_file))
print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
raw_input()

out_file = open(join(cwd, to_file), 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

Comment: `PS C:\Users\Schneeder> cd python
PS C:\Users\Schneeder\python> python test.py raw.txt copied.txt
Copying from raw.txt to copied.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    in_file = open(join(cwd, from_file))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Schneeder\\python\\raw.txt'
PS C:\Users\Schneeder\python>`

Comment: @user3047058 do you REALLY have that file in that directory? please, check.